# How to denoise a conversation between two people?

Tags: denoising, speech-processing

I would like to know how to determine (using any programming language) whether a given audio file contains noise, such as of people talking in background, how to remove the noise, and how to subsequently compare the cleaned file with the original file.

The input to the program will be a sound file containing a conversation between two people and the program should be able to remove the noise from that file and should output only the conversation between the two people.

Comment: What kind of noise?

Comment: @geometrikal, I am supposed to write a program which will remove all kind of noise. I have updated my question to give more information.

Comment: In DSP, usually 'to remove noise' means removing AWGN, or maybe spurious tones - so for your application, you just want to be able to segment out a users main voice, from other *voices*, is that correct? You dont care about AWGN at all?

Comment: @Mohammad, sorry for my lack of knowledge as I am new into DSP. I do not know much about AWGN but I think I have to remove AWGN also in order to get clear speech output.

Comment: You might start by researching the Wiener filter.

Comment: Search for articles on multiple speaker separation in the research journals.  It appears to still be a post-doc level research topic.

Comment: @hotpaw2, Is there any library or open source project which will give me ready made classes? It will be great if I get something like "Give your audio input to this class and this will reduce all the noise in it" because I am Software Developer by profession and my project deadline wont allow me experiment and invest lot of time on this thing.

Comment: @Shekhar: "Give your audio input to this class and this will reduce all the noise in it"  It's not that simple.  You'll need to provide more details.  How were the people recorded?  Is this a stereo or mono recording?  Is there any information about the type of noise?  Background chatter in a crowded room?  White noise from the microphone(s)?

Comment: This is a very tough problem and the topic of a lots of fundamental research and dozens of Ph.D. theses. The best approach depends highly on the recording method and the spatial, spectral & temporal properties of the noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're attempting to do is a case of blind source separation (check Wikipedia). There are many techniques to solve this kind of problem, maybe you could check those on the Wikipedia and use the one that fits your needs best.

Particularly, last year one of my teachers showed us a demo of the ICA algorithm, and we got to play round with it in MATLAB. It seemed really effective, and there's a research group that even created [this MATLAB toolbox](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/whatisica.shtml) for the ICA algorithm. [Here](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/cocktail/cocktail_en.cgi) you can check a simple demo (called cocktail party problem) of how ICA works and how effective it is.

Since you say you're new to DSP, I'm not sure if ICA or the other techniques would be too advanced for you, but maybe this will put you in the right direction. Good luck.

Comment: I believe ICA requires independent recordings of the two sources, with different mixes in each.  There's no mention of this in the question.